# Test for empty possibly itemized argument in tabu

Tags: tables, conditionals, itemize, tabu

For some reason, I can't test if `#2` is empty in the following `tabu` use case. An

> Incomplete \ifx; all text was ignored after line 14

is thrown executing the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newcommand \test [2]{%
%Works
%#1  \ifx&#2& empty \else  {\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}#2\end{minipage}} \fi

% Doesn't with Arg A
\begin{tabu}{XX} #1 & \ifx&#2& empty \else  {\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}#2\end{minipage}} \fi \end{tabu}
}

\begin{document}%
\test{A}{\begin{itemize}\item Test\end{itemize}} % Arg A
%\test{A}{}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to have something to do with how `tabu` examines cell contents. Adding a pair of braces helps.

I've also changed the emptiness test to something safer.

```
\newcommand\test[2]{%
  \begin{tabu}{XX}
  #1 &
  {\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax 
     empty%
   \else
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}#2\end{minipage}%
   \fi}
  \end{tabu}}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have

```
 \ifx&
```

when TeX sees the `&` the cell ends and Tex switches in the code that ends the column definition. So here the `\ifx` will compare the first two tokens in the closing definition of the `X` column type in tabu, The following uses a safer test for empty.

Apart from that it's not clear why you would want to put a minipage in a X column as X columns are already parboxes?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\makeatletter
\newcommand \test [2]{%
\begin{tabu}{XX}%
#1&%
\def\tmp{#2}%
\ifx\tmp\@empty
\expandafter\@firstoftwo
\else
\expandafter\@secondoftwo
\fi
{empty}%
{\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}#2\end{minipage}}%
\end{tabu}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}%
\test{A}{\begin{itemize}\item Test\end{itemize}} % Arg A
\test{A}{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It breaks also with `\ifx\relax#2\relax`

Comment: @egreg yes I noticed that:-) Changed to a safer test, I see you posted a different "safer test" in the meantime:-)