# How do I check if a list item is blank when it is passed as a parameter in LaTex?

Tags: etoolbox, optional-arguments, comma-separated-list

I'm trying to create a command that accepts two lists using the \listofitems package where  the first list is optional.

In the command I want to check if the first entry in the optional list is "blank", which according to the \listofitems documentation means it is either "empty or spaces". The default value for my optional list "\opt" is [ , -, -]. So from what I understand the first entry would be: " " so it would be blank. However, both \ifblank and \notblank seem to be reading as something else? Maybe?

I'm at a loss, here is some code demonstrating what I'm talking about:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{listofitems}

\newcommand{\myCommand}[2][  , -, -]{

\setsepchar{, }
\readlist\opt{#1}
\readlist\args{#2}

\noindent Using $\backslash$ifblank: \\
\ifblank{\opt[1]}{$\backslash$opt[1] is blank!}{$\backslash$opt[1] is not blank! Here it is: "\opt[1]"} \\ \\
Using $\backslash$notblank: \\
\notblank{\opt[1]}{$\backslash$opt[1] is not blank! Here it is: "\opt[1]"}{$\backslash$opt[1] is blank!} \\ \\
Test of $\backslash$ifblank: \\
\ifblank{ }{yep.}{nope.} \\
Test of $\backslash$notblank: \\
\notblank{ }{nope.}{yep.}
}

\begin{document}

\myCommand{blah, blah}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Optional arguments are easier since they are given default values which can be tested using `\ifx`.  The reccomended solution involves `\detokenize` and `\relax` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108518/test-for-empty-possibly-itemized-argument-in-tabu for example).

Comment: Here are ways to check whether an argument is empty: [How to check if a macro value is empty or will not create text with plain TeX conditionals?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53068/5764) (possible duplicate)